# Multi upload with javascript, html and laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, file, multi-upload

How can I do a multi-upload with javascript and HTML and Laravel 5.8, I want to show them to the user with there name, their progress,  and have the possibility to delete one of them before final upload just as shown in the image below :

[image]